# import excel files from list of urls

Tags: r, import, lapply

My goal is to create a list of data frames imported directly from urls. What I have now:

```
library(gdata)

urls <- list('https://minerals.usgs.gov/minerals/pubs/historical-statistics/ds140-chrom.xlsx',
    'https://minerals.usgs.gov/minerals/pubs/historical-statistics/ds140-coppe.xlsx',
    'https://minerals.usgs.gov/minerals/pubs/historical-statistics/ds140-nicke.xlsx',
    'https://minerals.usgs.gov/minerals/pubs/historical-statistics/ds140-tin.xlsx',
    'https://minerals.usgs.gov/minerals/pubs/historical-statistics/ds140-tungs.xlsx')


perl_dir <- 'C:/Strawberry/perl/bin/perl5.26.2.exe'
files <- lapply(urls, read.xls, perl = perl_dir)
```

When I run this I get the error:

> Error in xls2sep(xls, sheet, verbose = verbose, ..., method = method, 
>   :    Intermediate file
>   'C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpk9t4hG\file308c4520306c.csv'
>   missing! In addition: Warning message: running command
>   '"C:\STRAWB~1\perl\bin\PERL52~1.EXE"
>   "C:/Users/Mike/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/gdata/perl/xls2csv.pl" 
>   "https://minerals.usgs.gov/minerals/pubs/historical-statistics/ds140-chrom.xlsx"
>   "C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpk9t4hG\file308c4520306c.csv"
>   "1"' had status 22  Error in file.exists(tfn) : invalid 'file'
>   argument

I assume the invalid file argument means it can't find the file. Not sure how to correct it as the url is definitely correct.

Any ideas?

Comment: What package is `read.xls` from? Furthermore `.xls` and `.xlsx` are different. Please consider to use function that can read `.xlsx`, such as `read_excel` from the `readxl` package.

Comment: It's from the gdata package. read_excel is what I reached for first but as I understand it can't pull a file directly from a url.

Comment: I see. but I don't think `read.xls` can handle `xlsx` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to avoid downloading the files and than to import them, you can use the `rio` package. It has a wrapper around `readxl` (default) and `openxlsx` (not default), which allows you to import `xlsx` from urls. I use `rio` because `readxl` [doesn't have the ability to read urls](https://github.com/tidyverse/readxl/issues/278).

```
require(tidyverse)
require(rio)

urls <- list('https://minerals.usgs.gov/minerals/pubs/historical-statistics/ds140-chrom.xlsx',
             'https://minerals.usgs.gov/minerals/pubs/historical-statistics/ds140-coppe.xlsx',
             'https://minerals.usgs.gov/minerals/pubs/historical-statistics/ds140-nicke.xlsx',
             'https://minerals.usgs.gov/minerals/pubs/historical-statistics/ds140-tin.xlsx',
             'https://minerals.usgs.gov/minerals/pubs/historical-statistics/ds140-tungs.xlsx')


Myxlsx <- lapply(urls, FUN = rio::import)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks for pointing me to this package, I'll get a lot of use out of it.

Answer (score 2):

Why not do something like this (using the more robust `readxl` package):

```
urls <- list('https://minerals.usgs.gov/minerals/pubs/historical-statistics/ds140-chrom.xlsx',
    'https://minerals.usgs.gov/minerals/pubs/historical-statistics/ds140-coppe.xlsx',
    'https://minerals.usgs.gov/minerals/pubs/historical-statistics/ds140-nicke.xlsx',
    'https://minerals.usgs.gov/minerals/pubs/historical-statistics/ds140-tin.xlsx',
    'https://minerals.usgs.gov/minerals/pubs/historical-statistics/ds140-tungs.xlsx')

# Download files
mapply(download.file, unlist(urls), sapply(urls, basename))

# Read Excel files into a list of data.frames
library(readxl);
lst <- lapply(sapply(urls, basename), read_excel);
```

This produces local copies of the files, but if that's not a deal-breaker I recommend using `readxl`. To be honest, keeping copies of source data is always a good idea to ensure reproducibility and consistency of results.